# How Can Python Socket Programming be used to tranfer data in Shared Hosting?

Tags: python, sockets, shared-hosting

I am creating an application that uses the IOT/IOE (Internet of things) to communicate with sensors.

For this I have used Python Socket programming to Code the Sockets that communicate and JavaScript for the user end Display.

I am curious as to how I can implement this on a shared Hosting server? I know it is possible in a Dedicated Server where i have all the permissions.

If it is possible to use the sockets in shared hosting , I also want to know how feasible it is to do so ?

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This will depending entirely on the permissions of the shared host.

Comment: do you have ssh access to the server? often times they do not like long running proccesses...

Answer (score 0):

```
If it is possible to use the sockets in shared hosting , I also want 
to know how feasible it is to do so ?
```

As long as your socket end point is reachable in the Internet, you should be able to create and reach a socket just like the case of dedicated server. Typically, you should be able to request a public IP address on the shared host. Other than Internet reachability, sockets are application-layer semantics and so you don't need any special features.